# shows the value empty even after having value in text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a form where data are fetched from the server and is shown to the text field. Albeit the data is in text field, when i click on save button, i get error on all the fields displaying following fields cannot be empty. Also when i try to change the value, i cant get to type any text neither i can erase the text. Why the value is shown empty when having value over there?

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cloudinaryData: selectCloudinary()
});

class Cloudinary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cloudinary: {
      cloudinary_cloud_name: "",
      cloudinary_api_key: "",
    },
    errors: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadCloudinary();
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.setState(
      {
        cloudinary: {
          ...this.state.cloudinary,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      },
      () => {
        this.validateField([fieldName]);
      }
    );
  };


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.requestCloudinary(this.state.cloudinary);
  };

  render() {
    const { cloudinary, errors } = this.state;
    const { cloudinaryData } = this.props;
    if (cloudinaryData.size === 0) {
      return <div>Fetching Data...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="cloudinary_cloud_name"
          type="text"
          value={
            cloudinaryData
              ? cloudinaryData.cloudinary_cloud_name
              : cloudinary.cloudinary_cloud_name
          }
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          error={errors.cloudinary_cloud_name}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are setting the value to props instead of your state here:

```
<TextFieldGroup
  name="cloudinary_cloud_name"
  type="text"
  value={
    cloudinaryData
      ? cloudinaryData.cloudinary_cloud_name
      : cloudinary.cloudinary_cloud_name
  }
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  onBlur={this.handleBlur}
  error={errors.cloudinary_cloud_name}
/>
```

Instead, create a constructor and initialize your state to your props and replace your value to use state:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cloudinaryData: selectCloudinary()
});

class Cloudinary extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      state = {
          cloudinary: {
            cloudinary_cloud_name: props.cloudinaryData.cloudinary_cloud_name,
            cloudinary_api_key: props.cloudinaryData.cloudinary_api_key,
       },
       errors: {}
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadCloudinary();
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.setState(
      {
        cloudinary: {
          ...this.state.cloudinary,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      },
      () => {
        this.validateField([fieldName]);
      }
    );
  };


  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.requestCloudinary(this.state.cloudinary);
  };

  render() {
    const { cloudinary, errors } = this.state;
    const { cloudinaryData } = this.props;
    if (cloudinaryData.size === 0) {
      return <div>Fetching Data...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="cloudinary_cloud_name"
          type="text"
          value={cloudinary.cloudinary_cloud_name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          error={errors.cloudinary_cloud_name}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does constructor gets cloudinaryData when the network call is done in componentDidMount?

Comment: It should be updating store state that get's passed into this component as a prop. `this.props.loadCloudinary` should be firing off an action that dispatches to the store and saves the data from the request.